# Java: Accumulate output pattern in string variable?

Tags: java, string, for-loop, design-patterns, joptionpane

There is probably a question that covers this, but I haven't found it in searching. The idea is to display a pattern given user input for the character and number of lines like this:

```
x
xx
xxx
xxxx

xxxx
xxx
xx
x
```

But I need to use JOptionPane to do this. Here is what I have:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class loopPattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String in, num, output1 = null, output2 = "";
        int lines = 0;
        int i, n = 1;

        in = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the character for the pattern:");
        num = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the number of lines in the pattern:");
        lines = Integer.parseInt(num);

        for (i=1; i<=lines; i++) {

            for (n=1; n<=lines; n++) {

                output1 = (n +"\n");
            }
        }

        for (i=lines; i>=1; i--){

            for (n=lines; n>=1; n--){
                output2 = (n +"\n");
            }
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output1 +output2);
    }

}
```

I have to then make it repeat this pattern each time the user hits "Ok" and quit when they hit "Cancel". I think I can do that if I could just figure out the accumulating in a string variable thing. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accumulating in a string variable is called a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). It allows you to quickly append things into the StringBuilder from which you can call toString() to transform it back to a String.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (i=1; i<=lines; i++) {
    for (n=1; n<=lines; n++) {
        sb.append(n +"\n");
    }
}
```

if you can not use a StringBuilder, then use a String variable and assign it the value of itself with another string using the "+" operator. This can be shorthanded with "+="

```
String string = new String();
string = string + "stuff to go on the string";
// or as a shorthand equivalent
string += "stuff to go on the string";

/// loop example
String myoutput = new String();
for (i=1; i<=lines; i++) {
    for (n=1; n<=lines; n++) {
        myoutput += n +"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it that you could explain that does not include StringBuilder? It isn't in the chapter this exercise comes from and the professor didn't mention it in the assignment itself. I really appreciate any help - the professor employs the "sink or swim" approach and has refused to respond to inquiries about everything (including grades). So I'm kind of stuck.

Comment: Thanks. That works. Now I just have to figure out what else I've done wrong. :)

Answer (score 0):

As a high level approach, you could try this.  Create two `StringBuilder` instances.  Loop up until the desired `lines` is hit.  For each iteration, append an `X` into the first `StringBuilder` and then append to entire contents of that `StringBuilder` into the other one (via `toString`) with a `\n` for the newline.  After that loop finishes, append in 2 empty lines for the separators.  Then, loop until the first `StringBuilder` is empty, removing the last char for each iteration (via `deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1)`) and appending the entire content into the other `StringBuilder` again via `toString` plus `\n`.  When done, the second `StringBuilder` should have the patten you desire.

```
int lines = 4;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

StringBuilder pattern = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++){
  sb.append("X");
  pattern.append(sb.toString() + "\n");
}
pattern.append("\n\n");
pattern.append(sb.toString() + "\n");
while(sb.length() > 0){
  sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
  pattern.append(sb.toString() + "\n");
}

System.out.println(pattern.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

If using a StringBuilder is too advanced you can get the same effect simply using a string:

```
String output1 = "";
for (i=1; i<=lines; i++) {
    for (n=1; n<=lines; n++) {
        output1 = output1.concat(n +"\n");
        // note the below commented out code should also work:
        //output1 = output1 + n + "\n";
    }
}
```

This is much less efficient then using a StringBuilder though since a new string will be created and assigned to output1 for each iteration of the inner loop.

Comment: I'm sure it's less efficient, but I'm not to StringBuilder quite yet. This output1 = output1 + n + "\n"; is not working, though. I need the output1 to be in at n or in*n, if that makes sense. So I have to figure that out now.

Comment: looks like @user1676075 found the [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657513/java-accumulate-output-pattern-in-string-variable/16658361#16658361) to that by moving the new line concatenation to the outer loop. And 'A += B' is simply shorthand for 'A = A + B'

Answer (score 0):

Your loop shuold look more like:

```
for (i=1; i<=lines; i++) {

            for (n=0; n<i; n++) {

                output1 += in; 
            }
       output += "\n";
        }
```

assuming you can't use StringBuilder (which, per other posts, is a better option).